# withSchedule(ScheduleBuilder<SBT>) in the type TriggerBuilder<Trigger> is not applicable for arguments (MutableTrigger)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, quartz-scheduler

Following code gives error like : The method withSchedule(ScheduleBuilder) in the type TriggerBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (MutableTrigger)

```
   public static Trigger buildTriggerForJob(int hours, int minutes, int seconds, String name, String groupName) {
            return org.quartz.TriggerBuilder
                    .newTrigger()
                    .withIdentity(name, groupName)
                    .withSchedule(
                            SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInHours(hours).withIntervalInMinutes(minutes)
                            .withIntervalInSeconds(seconds).repeatForever().build());
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to do it `.build()`. Try without it.

```
public static Trigger buildTriggerForJob(int hours, int minutes, int seconds, String name, String groupName) {
    return org.quartz.TriggerBuilder
           .newTrigger()
           .withIdentity(name, groupName)
           .withSchedule(
                SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInHours(hours).withIntervalInMinutes(minutes)
                .withIntervalInSeconds(seconds).repeatForever()).build();
 }
```

Comment: thanks for the hint .. :) :) I got it resolved .build() is to be used at the end and not after repeatForever(); :) :)